# Adding logo in twitter bootstrap nav bar

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navigation

I have created a the basic navigation bar in twitter bootstrap . And I put logo on it . But the problem is , when I resize my window ,it lost responsiveness, I mean nav-collapsing doesn't work

Here is the code of my nav bar

```
<nav>
    <div class="navbar navbar-top">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="btn btn-navbar">
                    <span class="icon-th-list"></span>
                </a>
                <a href="#" class="brand"> aniya</a>
                <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav pull-right">
                        <li><a href="#">about us</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">contact us</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav> <!----nav--->
```

### Here is my CSS

```
body {
    position: relative; width: 960px; padding: 30px; margin: 30px auto 5px; background: white; -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 20px black;
}

    .navbar .navbar-inner {
        height: 120px;
        width: auto;
    }


    .navbar .navbar-inner .container .brand {
        background-image: url(img/sample%20logo.jpg);
        width:500px;
        height:100px;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;

        text-indent:-9999px;
    }
```

---

this is what I made

http://i47.tinypic.com/2uo5g76.jpg

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few issues here I think.

First off I'll assume that you are definitely loading up all of the responsive Bootstrap css etc onto your page?

Look at this page: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/examples/hero.html

It will show you exactly what files and html are required for responsiveness.

In your css above you have a set width placed on your body tag along with padding, margin etc. That doesn;t seem like the normal thing to do with a bootstrap page and I would guess that that will cause problems.

I'm not 100% sure if it will help but try adding the data attributes that they have on the button element onto your btn-navbar

```
<a class="btn btn-navbar">
 <span class="icon-th-list"></span>
</a>
```

Also I think why your navbar isn't collapsing may be because of the size of your logo image.

You may have to write in some media queries to deal with that - possibly supplying a smaller image for lower resolutions.

I hope that some of what I've said here helps you or at least sets you on the correct path.